# Is it possible to share files from Sharepoint on a Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint

I am not familiar at all with Sharepoint so came here for some advice?

I am working on a wordpress website that will allow files to be downloaded based on users permission. The files are saved and managed in Sharepoint. Is it possible to integrate these files with Wordpress or do I have to transfer them to Wordpress. There are 100's so I am hoping there is an easier way to do it rather than using the wordpress media manager?

Any advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: WordPress is hosted in Intranet environment ..? Or you are using SharePoint as an  Internet site ? ..

Comment: Hi Vinayak, It is a live (external) Wordpress website I created for a client. They have inquired about giving employees access to download files from the site and instead of uploading the files to Wordpress they want to link to them on Sharepoint. I have been researching what  I can about it but have no experience with Sharepoint so unsure what to advise them?